# Is reusing rules always slower than redefine with with tokens in Antlr4?

Tags: javascript, antlr4

I am profiling my Antlr4 generated parser in JavaScript. I have a few rules that match `ID | STRING`.

### Lexer

```
ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

STRING
 : '"' (~["\r\n] | '""')* ('"'|[\r\n])?
 ;
```

### Parser

```
name: ID | STRING ;

rule1: some other rules;
rule2: different rules

some: ID | STRING ;
different: ID | STRING ;
```

If I change `some` to `some: name;` and `different` to `different: name;` the performance goes down about 30%. (To parse a given code 100 times, time goes up from 1.5s to about 2s).

In this case, `name` is a terminal node in parser. So I would not assume a lot of overhead in itself. We have 8 other places using `ID | STRING`. That 30% was after I replaced all of them with `name`.

The testing code is:

```
x = B."method. {a, b} 1"(1,2)
```

In the above code, the following will be matched by "ID | STRING":

1. x
2. B
3. "metohd. {a, b} 1"
4. 1
5. 2

Is my assumption stated in the title correct?

Comment: I have also observed a similar parse time pattern in the Profile tab with the Intellij IDEA plugin.

Comment: Yes, you discovered one of several optimization techniques for Antlr. A fold operation (introducing a new rule for a sequence of RHS symbols) will always slow the runtime of the parse call. The opposite, an unfold refactoring, results in a faster parse time. Of course, an unfold operation may not have much impact if the rule is not used a lot. There are many other important optimization methods.

Comment: Hi @kaby76, could you please point me to some help content that talks about "many other important optimisation methods"? Google search does not return a lot of useful information so far, except for this one https://tomassetti.me/improving-the-performance-of-an-antlr-parser/.

Comment: Peng, There aren't many good sources for Antlr optimizations. But Tomassetti covers a lot. Maybe it's obvious, but replacing recursion with Kleene operators improves on parse time. It might be worth your time to read Parr's paper LL(*): The Foundation of the ANTLR Parser Generator, looking at when the parser ends up backtracking. Also worth considering is what you need out of the parse. Antlr constructs a CST, but you can construct an AST if needed and avoid the time converting from CST to AST after the parse.

Answer (score 1):

30% seems like a LOT (but that might be artificial in a very simple example)

Using a recursive descent parser, it would make sense that there would be *some* overhead in calling the name rule rather than recognizing either of two tokens.

I would think the overall impact would be negligible in a larger contest, unless this is a VERY fundamental part of your grammar that is used a LOT.

If you're feeling performance pain around it, then "unrolling" it might make some sense.  Of course, you'd lose the "name" context in your resulting parse tree.  That may be a good or a bad thing depending upon how you want to handle things.  (sometimes those extra parse tree nodes are just noise you have that can feel like an irritation, and other times, they are important pieces of information).

Comment: Yes. It is artificial and I was parse it 100 times to get a measurable and comparable result. However, I can say it is not negligible in this case. I have also tried to unrolling other places and not all "unrolling" gives measurable improvement. In this specific case, losing "name" is not important as I can use "some" and "different" in the context. I thought it would have improved the performance because we "reuse" a rule and it could be "cached". I was completely wrong in understanding how "caching" works in antlr4.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that is parsed.

Comment: In your example code, it appears that virtually ALL of the input would fall into this rule.  So that would certainly qualify as using it a LOT for parsing your input.  So I’m not surprised to see it make quite a difference (probably would not have bet on 30% though).   With such a simple grammar and input that hits that parser rule for pretty much everything,  it’s not much of a surprise that the overhead of the extra rule is detectable.  Interestering thread all the same.